# Regex - dollar sign only matches if another character follows

Tags: php, regex, dollar-sign

I know there are lot of threads about regex and dollar signs. But the one I read didn't help at all. I have this regex `\b(foo bar\$)s?\b` which should match `foo bar$` and `foo bar$s`. The thing is, the regex only matches `foo bar$s`.

For `\b(foo bar)s?\b` it works for `foo bar` and `foo bars`

The dollar is part of a name, so I can't remove it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It was regex in general - Even the Question is already answered, i'd be interrested, what else you would've needed.

Comment: I would have wanted to see sample input, desired output, actual output, and the code that produced it.  It's ambiguous from your post whether the problem had to do with the input you didn't show us or the code you didn't show us.  :)  (Your regex *would* match the string `'oh foo bar$baz'` and thus matched, as a substring, one of the strings you told us didn't match.)  John Kugelman made a charitable guess as to the problem and turned out to have guessed correctly.

Comment: Oh, okay -  I think the code doesn't matter because it's just regex and it's just the same for javascript, php or whatever. But you're right with 'oh foo bar$baz' - Of Course there should only match if theres a space after the dollar. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\b(foo bar\$)(s\b)?
```

`\b` matches word boundaries, which are defined as a word-character followed by a non-word character, or vice-versa. `$` is a non-word character so `$\b<space>` is a failed match since the `\b` is surrounded by non-word characters on both sides.

The solution is to only look for the second `\b` if it's after an `s`.

Comment: You are right - it works. I thought if i escape $ php would handle it as a word character. Thanks for the good explanation

Comment: As an aside, if I remember correctly, "word characters" in Latin 8859-1 are basically `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (plus umlauts, acutes, graves and so on) - so characters like `$` or `-` don't count.